# Can you help fix this java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm receiving this fantastic stack:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at test.Visual.selection(Visual.java:156)
at test.Menu.actionPerformed(Menu.java:161)
```

Visual.java -- line 156 is while statement

```
vidergrille();
decochage();
String[] temp=map.file.reader();
int index=map.sudoku.random(0,temp.length);
switch(levelofdifficulty){
    case 1:
        while(!(Integer.parseInt(temp[index].substring(85,temp[index].length()))<=5000)){
            index=map.sudoku.random(0,temp.length);
        }
        break;
```

Menu.java -- line 161 is map.supanel

```
else if(evt.getSource()==m123){
    try {
        map.supanel.selection(1);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You array is **empty**, so it does not have an element with `0` index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems going on here and it's not just the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. For that immediate problem, based on the error message, your array is empty and your code is trying to find the first element at index 0, which it can't because empty arrays have no elements.

That being said, based on what I can see from the context of your problem, it looks like you are trying to read some data from your file via the `String[] temp=map.file.reader();` line.

So, I would either fix that `reader()` function or the data it reads. Also, I would strongly encourage you to write some validation code for what you read from that function.

Comment: Ok so you were right. The array is indexed in a `.txt` file which the program was unable to find.